Is this an OK question for DBA SE site ? (related to Top mistakes developers make writing T-SQL that lead to performance problems)
I would really like to ask a particular question on DBA SE, in order to collect some knowledge from experienced DBAs and performance tuners, and this way have a good reference for my developers that I can share with (send them link to DBA SE question). Question is below, please review:
Topic: Most common mistakes developers make writing T-SQL that lead to Performance Problems
Question:
If you've had a goal of training team of developers to write T-SQL queries more efficiently in terms of performance, what would you include in the recommendations ? Could you provide a list of things that should be avoided, explanation of why, short examples, how this can be done better, and links to more detailed articles on particular topic(s).
Kind of "Top 10" T-SQL performance things that should be kept in mind or avoided.
Example:

keep as few joins as possible in a single SQL statement (because it gets harder for Query optimizer to guess how many rows will come out, hence bad execution plans ?)

break SQL statements in parts, put intermediate results in a temp table(s), instead of many joins ?

table variables (avoid in most situations because of no stats, no paralellism ? in which situation can be used?)

match variable data types (used in WHERE clause) to column's data type (don't try to use nvarchar variable for a varchar column !)

use SARGable conditions in the WHERE clause ? (what is this ? why?)

do not use a NOLOCK (why ?)

use batches, instead of updating/deleting large amounts of data in one go ?

....

do not use ORM entity framework because... write queries yourself (debatable... really ? why ? )

....


I thought it would be great to have all advice from Pros in a single place, with links and examples, so if you would like to try, please post your answer (and remember this is related to performance of resulting queries!)
p.s. advice for BI folks writing monster T-SQL queries are also welcome...
End of Question / My comments: I realize that Question may be not 100% fit for DBA SE, but - it can collect some good answers, and best one 'possibly' may be judged by number of upvotes. Just wanted to make sure I don't collect downvotes and close votes right away, if I post this question. So what do you think on above, and would you post and answer to this question ?
Tried googling, found very few articles (like this https://www.sqlshack.com/7-common-t-sql-query-mistakes/) - I need more information, from more people, in in a more concise form (like DBA SE answer), with links to related articles and examples. The goal is to have a question with several good answers, that can be shared with team of developers for training purposes.

In my opinion, this kind of question is difficult to answer with concise, repeatable advice that doesn't rapidly become out of date.  It would be more suitable for a blog-style set of posts about best-practices.
Looking at the main site for questions mentioning "best practices" already shows over 1,400 questions.
You may be interested in looking at the list of answers included in the canonical answers which also contains a wealth of good, usable, vetted advice.

If you open up the help centre and have a look at What topics can I ask about here? you will see the following information.

If you have a question about...

Database Administration including configuration and backup / restore
Advanced Querying including window-functions, dynamic-sql, and query-performance
Data Modelling and database-design, including referential-integrity
Advanced Programming in built-in server-side languages including stored-procedures and triggers.
Data Warehousing and Business Intelligence including etl, reporting, and olap
…then you're in the right place to ask your question!


So far your question is not on-topic but also not off-topic.

but, dba.se is not the right place to ask questions about...

Client-side programming - ask on Stack Overflow
Basic SQL - ask on Stack Overflow
Career advice, including salary or résumé - try Patrick McKenzie's Don't call yourself a programmer


Let's have a look at the What types of questions should I avoid asking section of the help centre.

You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page.

and

Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much.

However, ...

Some subjective questions are allowed, but “subjective” does not mean “anything goes”. All subjective questions are expected to be constructive. What does that mean? Constructive subjective questions:

inspire answers that explain “why” and “how”
tend to have long, not short, answers
have a constructive, fair, and impartial tone
invite sharing experiences over opinions
insist that opinion be backed up with facts and references
are more than just mindless social fun


All-in-all IMO your question could be on-topic even though it could have the tendency to have a book style answer to it.
In the end the community will decide if your question is deemed to be on-topic or not. That's the way it works.
